# How to avoid echo in curl_exec()?

Tags: php, curl

I'm working with cURL, and needing to change my headers after using curl_exec(). But this function displays result automatically. Code:

```
$ch=curl_init($redir);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By using [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/curl_setopt), you can set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to have [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/curl_exec) return the result instead of echoing it:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Direct Output

```
$ch=curl_init($redir);
curl_exec($ch); // echo ouput
curl_close($ch);
```

Return Output

```
$ch=curl_init($redir);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$result = curl_exec($ch); // return ouput
curl_close($ch);
```